# Assign a stylesheet to each page in a Dash multi page app

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash

I am merging 3 Dash apps that used to run independently into a multipage Dash app. One of the apps was built using Dash Bootstrap Components and uses the stylesheet dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP and two others don’t use bootstrap but a custom css stylesheet.

I understand I can load the two stylesheets and the last one takes precedence when there is a clash by calling:

```
app = dash.Dash(name, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP, 'assets/custom_styles.css'])
```

The two stylesheets arent’s very compatible and generate some graphical bugs that are in practice are painful to correct (element not aligned correctly for instance). I would like to minimize refactoring of the code and happy to keep two stylesheets.

Is it possible to assign a stylesheet to an app in the architecture which would greatly simplify my problem? The architecture is:

app.py

```
index.py
apps
|-- init.py
|-- app1.py
|-- app2.py
|-- app3.py
```

app1 uses bootstrap whilst app2 and app3 use a custom stylesheet. How could I say app1 uses one stylesheet and app2 another if possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

If found a kind of hacky workaround with Javascript and [clientside callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks).

Let's say for example that the `custom_styles.css` clashes with the bootstrap styles here:

```
.btn-primary {
  background-color: red;
}
```

`dbc.Button` also has a `btn-primary` class that sets a `background-color`, so the styles above would overwrite the `background-color` from Bootstrap.

What you could do is before you return the layout you dynamically set stylesheets in the document based on the current url `pathname`.

That could look something like this:

```
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash import Dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Location(id="url", refresh=False),
        html.Div(id="page-content"),
        dcc.Store(id="pathname"),
    ]
)

app1_layout = dbc.Button("Button", color="primary")
app2_layout = html.Button("Button", className="primary")

app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(pathname) {
      document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]').forEach(stylesheet => {
        stylesheet.remove()
      })
      const link = document.createElement('link')
      link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
      if (pathname == "/page-2") {
        link.setAttribute("href", "/assets/custom_styles.css")
      } else {
        link.setAttribute("href", "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css")
      }
      document.head.append(link)

      return pathname
    }
    """,
    Output("pathname", "data"),
    Input("url", "pathname"),
)


@app.callback(
    Output("page-content", "children"),
    Input("pathname", "data"),
)
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == "/page-2":
        return app2_layout

    return app1_layout


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

The clientside callback is executed when the pathname changes and outputs to a [`Store`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store) component's `data` property. A regular callback that returns the layout has this property as an input, so the callback will be fired when it changes.